# Ripping or downloading large number of selected pages from wikipedia

Tags: database, ripping, wikipedia

I require only subject related articles from wikipedia i.e. ,not the entire database but specific pages, for offline viewing and reference purpose. the download page of wikipedia allows download of meta content or entire data base which contains plethora of unrelated subjects , general articles and news etc, which are of lesser value to me. how can i download all articles in wikipedia related to single subject at a time ( it will help  from context switching) it will also save disk space and time. i ask this because there are few apps available on play store which provide subject specific wikipedia articles.

Comment: Use [Special:Export](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export) or a tool like [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/). Or [build your own zimfile](https://openzim.org/wiki/Build_your_ZIM_file) although that's considerably more complex.